# Character model glitch when I activate my horse

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I know this glitch rarely happens, but I encountered this glitch for real. Here's what happened:

## My Story About the Glitch

So one time I bought a horse at the Leyawiin Stables. I rode it around the country to find some caves and ruins. Then I was attacked by an animal. I killed it and then I went back to my horse, when I activated it, my character started to bend backwards and half of my body went inside my legs and back up instead of going on the horse. It was only a few minutes until my player got back on the horse.

For those who don't understand, this also happened to that Black Horse Courier too except she was already on the horse the glitch happened.

[Another person encountered this too.](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/927345-the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion/48118387)

So how do I fix this glitch so I don't have to wait too long?

Comment: So... what's the question?

Comment: @JasonHeine I edited so you should now see what I'm asking.

Comment: [Might be fixed by the Unofficial Oblivion Patch](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Horses#Bugs)